# Swift 3 CocoaPod does not pass lint

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift3

I’m upgrading a CocoaPod to Swift 3. It compiles and runs just fine, but `pod lib lint` fails with numerous compiler errors, because the linter tries to compile everything as Swift 2.3.

Attempts to set `SWIFT_VERSION` in the podspec or change “Use Legacy Swift Language Version” in my framework’s Xcode project do not solve the issue.

How do I make the pod linter use Swift 3?

Comment: Same problem here, cannot lint !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It turns out CocoaPods now looks for a `.swift-version` file, as of 1.1.0.rc.2 ([changelog](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/77d6a4a562e26ad2242578f7c2582af9851e61f5/CHANGELOG.md#110rc2-2016-09-13)). If the file contains `3.0`, linting will work:

```
echo 3.0 > .swift-version
```

Comment: awesome, help me fixed the issue.

Comment: @KyleGoslan Didn't work for me until I pushed that file to my repo :|

Answer (score 5):

First you have to update cocoapods to 1.1.0.rc.2 by

```
[sudo] gem install cocoapods --pre
```

then as Paul Cantrell says, do

```
echo 3.0 > .swift-version
```

in the same dir where the pod spec is

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue when develop SDK which is depending on socket.io-Client-Swift.
After type

```
echo 3.0 > .swift-version
```

still don't fix my problem.

However, I noticed pod lint use xcodebuild to test whether the framework is ready to be release without error. 
Make sure you use Xcode8 to build pod lint. For some reason, I install both Xcode7 & Xcode8 and changed my xcodebuild path to xcode7, so the lint won't be pass when I want to make a framework with swift 3.

use the following code to make sure your xcode setting is right.

```
xcode-select -print-path
```

if the xcode-select path is not point to xcode8, you should using

```
xcode-select -switch <path>
```

set the xcode-select path to xcode8 which is usually in your Applications.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was written for Swift 3, but you can do the same to update pods for 4.0:

```
echo 4.0 > .swift-version
```

This was done with version 1.3.1 of Cocoapods.